# Правильно ли расставлены запятые.

Tags: пунктуация

```
Смешиваясь с солеными морскими ветрами, запах цитрусовых создает, целебно действующую на людей атмосферу.
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае нет оснований для употребления запятой в этом месте (между сказуемым и прямым дополнением это противоестественно и бросается в глаза - напр. здесь невозможна речевая пауза). Если же подойти к этому формально (обратиться к правилам, выведенным из устройства языка), то причастный оборот в функции определения не обособляется, если стоит непосредственно перед определяемым словом (при этом отсутствуют обстоятельства, требующие отнести этот случай к исключениям):

http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/Синтаксис_и_пунктуация/Причастный_оборот

Answer (score 0):

Перед "целебно" запятая не нужна.

Comment: @Alex_ander, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.